# Correlativo filas de tabla PHP y MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql

Estoy trabajando con PHP y MYSQL, tengo una lista que muestra todas las solicitudes ingresadas. La primera columna es ID y muestra el numero de la solicitud. Tengo un código para la paginación y muestro 10 registros por pagina. El problema que tengo es que en la primera pagina el ID funciona bien y muestra del 1 al 10, pero al entrar a l segunda pagina deberia comenzar con 11, pero el contador de reinicia y comienza de 1 nuevamente.
Les comparto mi codigo, esperando que alguien pueda ayudarme a resolver esto.

Utlizo count_id para mostrar el numero ID

```
 function count_id()
 {
   static $count = 1;
   return $count++;
 }

 $sql_register = $db->query("SELECT COUNT(*) as total_registro FROM pasantia");
            $result_register = mysqli_fetch_array($sql_register);
            $total_registro = $result_register['total_registro'];
       
          $solicitudesPorPagina = 10;
          $pagina = 1;

          if (isset($_GET["pagina"])) 
          {
              $pagina = $_GET["pagina"];
          }
          $limit = $solicitudesPorPagina;
          $offset = ($pagina - 1) * $solicitudesPorPagina;
          $paginas = ceil($total_registro / $solicitudesPorPagina);



   $query = $db->query("SELECT 
   p.id,p.fecha_solicitud,p.nombre_docente,p.rut,p.email,p.telefono,p.titulo,p.fecha_inicio,
                            p.fecha_termino,p.registro_sis,e.name AS 
   nombre_establecimiento,c.nombre_carr AS nombre_carrera
                            FROM pasantia p INNER JOIN carr c ON c.id = p.carrera INNER JOIN 
   establecimiento e ON e.id = p.campo_formador
                            ORDER BY p.fecha_solicitud DESC LIMIT $offset, 
    $solicitudesPorPagina"); 
        }

        $result = mysqli_num_rows($query);
        if($result > 0)
        {
          while ($data = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) 
          {
          ?>
            <tr>
            <td class="text-center"><?php echo count_id();?></td>
            <td class="text-center"> <?php echo read_date($data['fecha_solicitud']); ?></td>
            <td class="text-center" > <?php echo remove_junk($data['nombre_docente']); ?></td>
            <td class="text-center"> <?php echo remove_junk($data['rut']); ?></td>
            <td class="text-center"> <?php echo remove_junk($data['nombre_carrera']); ?></td>
            <td class="text-center"> <?php echo remove_junk($data['nombre_establecimiento']); 
   ?></td>
            <td class="text-center"> <?php echo date('d-m-Y', 
   strtotime($data['fecha_inicio'])); ?></td>
            <td class="text-center"> <?php echo date('d-m-Y', 
   strtotime($data['fecha_termino'])); ?></td>
            <td class="text-center">
              <div class="btn-group">
                <a href="editar_pasantia.php?id=<?php echo (int)$data['id'];?>" class="btn 
  btn-info btn-xs"  title="Editar" data-toggle="tooltip">
                  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span>
                </a>
                 <a href="eliminar_pasantia.php?id=<?php echo (int)$data['id'];?>" class="btn 
   btn-danger btn-xs"  title="Eliminar" data-toggle="tooltip">
                  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span>
                </a>
              </div>
            </td>
          </tr>
        <?php
          }
        }
        ?>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


////// PAGINACION //////

 <nav aria-label="Page navigation example">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6">

        <p>Mostrando <?php echo $solicitudesPorPagina ?> de <?php echo $total_registro ?> 
  solicitudes disponibles</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
        <p>Página <?php echo $pagina ?> de <?php echo $paginas ?> </p>
    </div>
</div>
<ul class="pagination justify-content-right">
    <!-- Si la página actual es mayor a uno, mostramos el botón para ir una página atrás -->
    <?php if ($pagina > 1) { ?>
        <li>
            <a href="./pasantia.php?pagina=<?php echo $pagina - 1 ?>">
                <span aria-hidden="true">&laquo;</span>
            </a>
        </li>
    <?php } ?>

    <!-- Mostramos enlaces para ir a todas las páginas. Es un simple ciclo for-->
    <?php for ($x = 1; $x <= $paginas; $x++) { ?>
        <li class="<?php if ($x == $pagina) echo "active" ?>">
            <a href="./pasantia.php?pagina=<?php echo $x ?>">
                <?php echo $x ?></a>
        </li>
    <?php } ?>
    <!-- Si la página actual es menor al total de páginas, mostramos un botón para ir una 
   página adelante -->
    <?php if ($pagina < $paginas) { ?>
        <li>
            <a href="./pasantia.php?pagina=<?php echo $pagina + 1 ?>">
                <span aria-hidden="true">&raquo;</span>
            </a>
        </li>
     <?php } ?>
   </ul>
 </nav>
```

Comment: Por favor ¿podrías [edit] tu pregunta y agregar el código de la función `count_id`?

Comment: LIsto, lo acabo de agregar

Comment: ¿Quisieras modificar el funcionamiento de `count_id`? Por que podrías simplemente sumarle `$offset` al imprimir. Ejemplo: `<?php echo count_id() + $offset;?>`

Comment: Me resulto, te lo agradezco..

Comment: Si es lo que buscabas, lo pongo como respuesta así podes votarla y/o marcarla como "aceptada".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podrías simplemente sumarle `$offset` al imprimir `count_id()`.

#### Ejemplo:

```
<?php echo count_id() + $offset;?>
```